# Regarding the solutions to this ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, bessel-functions, frobenius-method

For the ODE $$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4x^2y=0$$ I assumed a solution in the form $$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$ and I managed to get the following recursive definition:
$$a_{n+4}=-\dfrac{4}{(n+3)(n+4)}a_n$$ Given $a_0$, I get one solution $$y_1=a_0\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}x^4+\dfrac{1}{42}x^8 ...\right)$$
and given $a_1$, I get another solution $$y_2=a_0\left(x-\dfrac{1}{5}x^5+\dfrac{1}{90}x^9 ...\right)$$
I recognise this as a second order ODE, and so I expect only two linearly independent solutions. The thing is, if I was given an $a_2$ or an $a_3$, then don't I get another two linearly independent solutions? This means I have four solutions, which doesn't make any sense. I'm assuming $a_2$ and $a_3$ solutions must therefore be dependent with respect to the ones I listed, but I can't see it.

Comment: This is a parabolic cylinder ODE : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 1):

Good question. If you actually look at the bottom few terms of the power series $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$ once you substitute it in, you find
$$ 0 = 2a_2 + 6a_3 x + x^2(4a_0+12a_4)+x^3(4a_1+20a_5) + \dotsb, $$
so in fact when one equates coefficients, the $a_2$ and $a_3$ have to vanish anyway: the derivative only lops off the first two terms. This shows the importance of examining the base of the series, as well as the recurrence relation.

Comment: How exactly did you get that expression? I'm having trouble seeing why that expression implies the other terms will vanish.

Comment: That's $y''+4x^2y$, which is zero. Hence every coefficient of every power of $x$ is zero. The general term gives you the recurrence, the bottom terms the number of solutions and their first terms. In this case, the equations for the constant term and the linear term are $2a_2$ and $6a_3$. Since these terms have to vanish, both of these must be zero.

Comment: Forgive me, but I still don't know how you derived the expression. Did you use the recurrence relationship, because I can't seem to get it myself.

Comment: For the Method of Frobenius, you substitute $y=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$ into the differential equation, then equate coefficients of $x^n$ to get the recurrence. But you also have to look at the first few terms to find the initial conditions for the recurrence. This is what that expression is.